# ASP.NET Core Bootstrap 4 Accordion only partially expanding

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to generate an accordion dynamically using bootstrap and ASP.NET Core.
The goal is to show all terms which belong to a certain category but the problem is that only the first two out of four categories are expanding/collapsing. I can see, that each card-header and card-body is available in the DOM.
My code looks like this:

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    @foreach (var category in this.Model.Categories)
    {
        var random = Guid.NewGuid();
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="@random">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@category.Id" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@category.Id">
                        @category.CategoryName
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            @foreach (var term in category.Terms)
            {
                <div id="@category.Id" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="@random" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @term.GermanTranslation
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML has 2 problems:

- The ID for `.collapse` is not unique. You used `@category.Id` within the terms loop.
- You only used a digit as the ID for `.collapse`.

  - You might get away with this restriction in HTML5, but [in HTML4, the ID must begin with a letter](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

To me, generating the random number as card header's ID is unnecessary either. An accordion doesn't need an ID for each card header to work. You can use the category ID for the collapsible panels instead.

You said you would like to show all terms which belong to a certain category. Then the collapsible should be for each category, not for each term within a category. Your `foreach` loop for category terms should be inside `.card-body`.

I would suggest you give the following a try:

```
<div class="accordion" id="category-accordion">
    @foreach (var category in this.Model.Categories)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" 
                      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#category-@category.Id">
                        @category.CategoryName
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="category-@category.Id" class="collapse data-parent="#category-accordion">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    @foreach (var term in category.Terms)
                    {
                        <li class="list-group-item">@term.GermanTranslation</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This is generating collasible panel for each category, containing multiple translations.